# Custom jQuery Functions and Arguments

Tags: jquery

I have written this scirpt:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#tb1 li').hover(function () {
    var head = $(this).attr("title");
    var image = $(this).find("a").attr("rel");
    $('.aCnt img').attr("src", image);
    $('.aCnt span').html(head);

   });
    $('#tb1 li').eq(0).hover();
});
```

I want to make this script global

```
function interActive(myID, myClass){
    ID = '#' + myID;
    cls = '.' + myClass;
     $('ID li').hover(function () {
    var head = $(this).attr("title");
    var image = $(this).find("a").attr("rel");
    $('cls img').attr("src", image);
    $('cls span').html(head);

   });
    $('ID li').eq(0).hover();
}
```

I know that jQuery function not similar to for example php functions. The `interActive` functions will not work in jQuery. How can I modify this function for jQuery?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables ID and cls are being treated literally as strings when put them inside quotes. You need to concatenate them like this: `cls + ' img'`.

```
function interActive(myID, myClass){
    var ID = '#' + myID;
    var cls = '.' + myClass;
    $(ID + ' li').hover(function () {
        var head = $(this).attr("title");
        var image = $(this).find("a").attr("rel");
        $(cls + ' img').attr("src", image);
        $(cls + ' span').html(head);

    });
    $(ID + 'li').eq(0).hover();
}
```

You may also consider writing a jQuery plugin for this, such as:

```
$.fn.interActive = function (target) {
    this.find('li').hover(function () {
        var head = $(this).attr('title');
        var image = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
        $(target).find('img').attr('src', image);
        $(target).find('span').html(head);
    }).eq(0).hover();
};
```

Which can be used like this:

```
$("#someID").interActive(".someClass");
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/EkKSS/1/ .There is not any change in hover.

Comment: You used the first method, which doesn't create a jQuery plugin, so you call it simply using `interActive(..., ...)`. You also need to put any strings (not variables containing strings) inside quotes. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gNFA3/

Comment: Thanks for great plugin method.